# Copy a disk in another VM in Azure (using Graphic Interface)

Tags: azure, disk-image

I'd like to copy a disk of a VM and use it in another VM.

I see that there are many tutorials to do it, but they suggest to use PowerShell, bash, ecc. But I don't want to spend time to learn how to use them (I have never used PoweShell), I guess that from the dashboard this should be pretty easy. But I didn't find anything that suggests how to do it.

**QUESTION**

Does anyone know ho to copy a VM's disk and use it in another VM using mainly the dashboard (I guess that Azure should provide a service like this)?

Comment: In the current state of the web gui (Jan 2018) this is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some attempts I managed to figure out how to do it by Graphic Interface, using only 2 bash commands to mount the copied disk.

Here I report the steps to achieve this task (sorry if the screenshots are in Italian, I can't change the language of Azure interface):

1. go on the [top of the menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sgAO.png), in the search-bar and type "snapshot", for then clicking on the Snapshot service
2. click on [add button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrLkL.png)
3. in the new [menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkKnE.png) select the source disk that you want to copy ("Disco di origine" in Italian)
4. when created the snapshot of the disk that we want to copy, go in the search-bar of the 1st point and this time search for "disks", for then clicking on Disks service
5. click on add button just like in the 2nd point
6. here in [Source snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qjhY.png) ("Snapshot di origine" in Italian), you can specify the snapshot that has been just created

At this point we have a copy of the disk, now we want to use it as a disk for another VM. So:

1. go on the desired VM to which we want to attach the disk and search for ["Disks"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZnXK.png) and click there
2. click on "Add data disk" on the bottom of the new menu
3. select the disk that has been just created
4. connect in SSH to the VM (I assume you are using Ubuntu server and so bash command line) and type `sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sdc /path/of/mounting/point`
5. type `sudo nano /etc/fstab` and edit the file adding the following line

   `/dev/sdc    /datadrive   ext4   defaults,nofail   1   2`

(I have not enough reputation to post picture here, please help me to reach only 10 and I can post here the screenshots)

Answer (score 0):

Try  Azure Storage Explorer.

It provides a GUI to fully manage your storage accounts (Unless they are managed disks).